# Clear contents of file

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I am trying to remove the contents text file for iOS.

Alternatively, I could delete the file then re-create it right after with no contents.

For this solution, I know I can delete the file using `[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];`. Recreating the file is the hard part for me.

I am locating the file just fine using the following code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
}

//code to recreate the same file, just with no content
```

Comment: What happens if you try `-[createFileAtPath:path contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil]`?

Comment: I could potentially try this, but I am trying to create a blank file with no data. Could I possibly just send it a null data value for its contents?

Comment: `[NSData data]` is no data. Passing `nil` will result in error.

Comment: I got it, it seems to be working. It's late for me and I was trying to us createFileAtDirectory which has been deprecated. Silly error on my part for not finding createFileAtPath. Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
-[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil]
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could create a `FileHandle` instance and call `truncateFile()`, like this:

```swift
var myFileHandle: FileHandle?
var fileName = "your_file_name.ext"

let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let docPath = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(fileName)

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: docPath.path) {
    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: docPath.path, contents: Data(), attributes: nil)
}

do {
    myFileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: docPath)
    myFileHandle?.truncateFile(atOffset: 0)
} catch let error {
    print("Could not initialize File Handle. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```